# Custom Tokens not appearing in Mist. How do I watch for tokens?

Tags: mist, tokens

I purchased some first blood tokens and sent them to my mist wallet. They are listed under contracts, Then custom contracts. I'm trying to send some to another address and not having any luck. I created a quick 1:30 minute video explaining my dilemma. Here it is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gUU0BzBXO0A

Comment: Offering [bounties](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) is only allowed via reputation.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to [Watch The Firstblood Token Contract](https://github.com/bokkypoobah/TokenTrader/wiki/1ST-%E2%80%90-First-Blood#how-to-watch-the-token-contract-in-ethereum-wallet--mist).

And you will need to [Watch The Firstblood Token](https://github.com/bokkypoobah/TokenTrader/wiki/1ST-%E2%80%90-First-Blood#how-to-watch-the-token-in-ethereum-wallet--mist).

#### Mist Send Tokens

You should then be able to send your Firstblood tokens to another address using the Mist send transaction function.

#### Token Contract `transfer(...)` Function

Alternatively, you can interact with the Firstblood token contract, and execute the [Transfer function](https://github.com/bokkypoobah/TokenTrader/wiki/GNT-%E2%80%90-Golem-Network-Token#how-to-transfer-your-tokens-in-ethereum-wallet--mist) to send your Firstblood tokens to another address. Note that the transfer instructions are for Golem Network Tokens (GNTs) but the same steps are involved as for Firstblood tokens.

Note that Firstblood tokens have 18 decimal places, so to transfer 1.23 1ST tokens, you have to specify 1230000000000000000 in the value field.