# How do I set up Ethereum / Mist wallet to watch for GNT

Tags: mist, tokens

I'm interested in exchanging some ETH for GNT, and send it to my Ethereum wallet. I understand that as a token, I will send it from the exchange to my Mist wallet address. Then how to I configure Mist, so that it watches and displays the GNT tokens?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Tokens in Mist Problem](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13842/custom-tokens-in-mist-problem)

Comment: I found the answer here: https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/Golem_Network_Token#How_To_Watch_The_Token_In_Ethereum_Wallet_.2F_Mist